# page size differs in LATEX output of pdf document

Tags: pdftex, linux

I am having the pdf output generated via `latex` but the first page size is bit broader despite having described the parameters in the preamble of the document. See image.

[image: the width is differing in the image.]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, inner=3cm, outer=3cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm, bindingoffset=2cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[stable]{footmisc}
\definecolor{mblue1}{rgb}{.2,1,1}
\sethlcolor{mblue1}


\title{Notes on Computational International Studies\\
    \large Conceptual Ideas}
\author{Writings Extracted from Many Sources}
\date{January 2021}

\begin{document}
    \sloppy
    \maketitle
    \tableofcontents
    \clearpage
......
\end{document}
```

Additionally, just to clarify the pdf viewer I am using is `Okular` in `Manjaro Linux`.  Even margins are distorted.

Also, the `Foxit pdfviewer` in windows platform gives no distortion. So, is it a `Linux` specific problem?

Comment: With the code in your question, I cannot reproduce the problem: all pages are of the same size, also with `okular`. Please make sure that your sample code illustrates the problem.

Comment: please post an example that demonstrates the problem. (it would seem you have used `\newgeometry` or a similar command at some point.

Comment: Is there a reason you set the tag `pdfpages`?

Comment: I believe the code seems to be ok. But, the output isn't. The native browser in `texstudio` shows pages uniform.